# Someone could me to understand the flow of this program?

Tags: java

My question is what they do " smallest" variable and the if statement. I know what the program do but it cost me to understand well the flow  execution of  this part .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IndexOfSmallest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while(true){
            int numbers = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
            if(numbers == 9999){
                break;
            }
            list.add(numbers);
        }
        int index;
        int smallest = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            int number = list.get(i);
            if ( smallest > number){
                smallest = number;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(smallest);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. It updates the value of `smallest` if a smaller number is found, for every number in the list. I would recommend either adding console logs, or stepping with a debugger, or my preference, "play computer" with a pencil and paper and trace it out by hand.

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are generally [too broad to be on-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions). If you don't describe what specific part of it you don't understand, how can we evaluate whether an answer successfully explains that piece?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simple console application. You should try to read your code line by line when you are starting to learn a new language.

This way you can show some effort and ask more clear and concise questions. Here is an example to go about reading your code line by line. If you don't know what some function is doing, look up that function.

Just take your time, you'll get used to the syntax and it will get easier every time.

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Create scanner taking console inputs
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // Create list

while(true){ // Endlessly loop
  // Keep reading input from console until user inputs 9999, then break
  int number = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
  if(number == 9999){
    break;
  }
  list.add(number); // Add number to list
}
/* int index; // This is worthless, not used again */
int smallest = list.get(0); // Variable to store smallest number
for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){ // Increase i until list size is reached
  int number = list.get(i); // Get number for position i in list
  if ( smallest > number){ // Compare
    smallest = number; // Set new smallest number
  }
}
System.out.println(smallest); // Print
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point regarding questions that "...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem". If we don't know what the OP's specific misunderstanding was (what research they did before asking here, what was still unclear after that research, etc), how can we tell if your answer clears it up?